# Getting screen width from another class

Tags: c#, xna

I have a `GameObject` class (I made by myself) and I wanted to create (for example) a `GraphicsWidth` variable that contains the maximum width of the screen. This means I need to create a `GraphicsDeviceManager` instance. (right?). This is what I did:

```
protected GraphicsDeviceManager GM;

public int GraphicsWidth
{
    get
    {
        return GM.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width;
    }
}
```

And it says that I need to use "new" (initialize the object). How can I do that from my GameObject class?

Edit: Please, can anyone try to help?

Answer (score 1):

The reason for your error is that you've declared a variable to hold the `GraphicsDeviceManager`, but you're not initializing it yet. You need to either new up your variable:

```
protected GraphicsDeviceManager GM = new GraphicsDeviceManager();
```

or you need to declare the `GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice` as static and make the change like so:

```
return GraphicsDeviceManager.GraphicsDevice.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width;
```

As comments above have indicated, you've got quite a few choices. Without knowing more context, I'd prefer using a single static container for a single instance of your `GraphicsDeviceManager` without making `GraphicsDeviceManager` static. Like this

```
public static class MyGraphics{
    public static readonly GraphicsDeviceManager DeviceManager = new GraphicsDeviceManager();

    public int ScreenWidth{
        get{ return DeviceManager.Viewport.TitleSafeArea.Width; }
    }
}
```

So it's similar to Itamar's solution.

Answer (score 0):

I don't get why would you create another GraphicsDeviceManager inside each GameObject instance.
All you need to do is call the `GraphicsDeviceManager.PreferredBackBufferWidth()` function. If you need to access it from GameObject you can declare a static GraphicsDeviceManager. That's what I usually do.

Perhaps I misunderstood your question. If so, please clarify what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Let me understand what you are saying,

Comment: if not, please upload it to Ideone or something and let me know what do you mean, thanks alot.

Comment: I prefer putting the GDM in a static class, like [this](http://ideone.com/JVBwM).